# Meaning of Bullets within Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, notation

I am working through the derivation for a method published in this [paper](https://www.cell.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0002-9297%2815%2900365-1). On page 586 (equation A1) the authors use the notation:

$$ N(\bullet,\bullet) $$

What do the bullets represent?  Do they imply any mean and variance will satisfy the following steps, a specific mean and variance previously written should be assumed, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation serves to shorten the notation for the distribution of $\beta_i$ as the equation is complicated enough. The distribution of $\beta_i$ is given previously on top of page 585. You can verify this by plugging in an Expectation of $0$ and a standard deviation of $\frac{h^2}{Mp}$.